snackbar shows again whenever I rotate my screen
I am having an error in my apk. After first snackbar shows, whenever I rotate my screen it shows that snackbar again.I don't want to show any snackbar, whenever my screen rotates. It happens for RegistrationUiState.Error state.
Could anyone please help me to identify the problem? If you want the full code, please refer to this https://github.com/openMF/mifos-mobile/pull/2565 or ask me if you need any part
this is what I have as my code
@Composable
fun UpdatePasswordScreen(
    viewModel: UpdatePasswordViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
    navigateBack: () -> Unit
) {
    val uiState by viewModel.updatePasswordUiState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

    UpdatePasswordScreen(
        uiState = uiState,
        navigateBack = navigateBack
    )
}

@Composable
fun UpdatePasswordScreen(
    uiState: RegistrationUiState,
    navigateBack: () -> Unit
) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val snackbarHostState = remember { SnackbarHostState() }

    Scaffold(snackbarHost = {
        SnackbarHost(hostState = snackbarHostState)
    }, topBar = {
        MifosTopBar(
            title = { Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.change_password)) },
            navigateBack = navigateBack
        )
    }) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(it)
        ) {
            UpdatePasswordContent()

            when (uiState) {
                is RegistrationUiState.Loading -> {
                    MifosProgressIndicator(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxSize()
                            .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background.copy(0.8f))
                    )
                }

                is RegistrationUiState.Error -> {
                    LaunchedEffect(snackbarHostState) {
                        snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(
                            context.getString(R.string.could_not_update_password_error),
                            context.getString(R.string.dialog_action_ok),
                            duration = SnackbarDuration.Short
                        )
                    }
                }

                is RegistrationUiState.Initial -> Unit

                is RegistrationUiState.Success -> {
                    LaunchedEffect(snackbarHostState) {
                        snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(
                            context.getString(R.string.password_changed_successfully),
                            context.getString(R.string.dialog_action_ok),
                            duration = SnackbarDuration.Short
                        )
                    }
                    navigateBack.invoke()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

here UpdatePasswordContent() constains screen content. Let me please know if you need anything else

The problem is that when a device is rotated a configuration change causes the entire activity to be recreated so the LaunchedEffect is running again

@tyczj any ways to fix this?

The reason is that activity recreates and composition restarts.
You can use rememberSaveable method, with it you can to retain state across activity and process recreation.
For your case you can just save boolean value for indicating show snackbar or not.
Simple example:
var showSnackBar by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(true) }

...
Scaffold(snackbarHost = {
        SnackbarHost(hostState = snackbarHostState)
    }) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(it)
        ) {
            if (showSnackBar) {
                LaunchedEffect(snackbarHostState) {
                    snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(
                        "Message",
                        "label",
                        duration = SnackbarDuration.Short
                    )
                    showSnackBar = false
                }
            }
        }
    }

UPDATE:
Actually, in my opinion this design is little bit uncorrect.
Here you just want to show a message with snack bar.
It is more like one time event, and not a screen state.
It's easier and I think it's better to do it like this with shared flows:
Screen:
@Composable
fun UpdatePasswordScreenRoot(
    viewModel: UpdatePasswordViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    UpdatePasswordScreen(
        events = viewModel.events,
        onButtonClick = viewModel::onButtonClick
    )
}

@Composable
private fun UpdatePasswordScreen(
    events: Flow<RegistrationUiEvent>,
    onButtonClick: () -> Unit
) {
    val snackBarHostState = remember { SnackbarHostState() }

    val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current
    Scaffold(snackbarHost = {
        SnackbarHost(hostState = snackBarHostState)
    }) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(it)
        ) {
            Box {
                Button(onClick = onButtonClick) {
                    Text(text = "New snack bar message")
                }
            }

            LaunchedEffect(events, lifecycleOwner.lifecycle) {
                lifecycleOwner.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
                    withContext(Dispatchers.Main.immediate) {
                        events.collect { event ->
                            when (event) {
                                is RegistrationUiEvent.Error -> {

                                    snackBarHostState.showSnackbar(
                                        "error message",
                                        "ok",
                                        duration = SnackbarDuration.Short
                                    )
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

ViewModel:
@HiltViewModel
class UpdatePasswordViewModel  @Inject constructor() : ViewModel() {

    private val _events = MutableSharedFlow<RegistrationUiEvent>()
    val events = _events.asSharedFlow()

    fun onButtonClick() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _events.emit(RegistrationUiEvent.Error)
        }
    }
}


but it will show the snackbar only once. that is the main problem.

why?
it should show once only, right?

what if the user clicks the button 3 times, and there is error all the 3 times? We need to show that error snackbar 3 times right?
But if I use above code, it will show error only once. so the user won't understand if there is more error
so i need it to show more than once @MansiTanna

Can't paste all text into comment to previous answer so just add an another answer)
Yes, it shows only once cause showSnackBar never changes to true again in an example.
The code is just an example that rememberSaveable saves state even after screen rotation, and you need play around this.
You can base on snack bar message, and writes somesing similar to this:
var messageCount = 0

@Composable
fun UpdatePasswordScreen() {
    var message by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("Message") }
    SnackBarComposable(
        message
    ) {
        message = "New message ${++messageCount}"
    }
}

@Composable
fun SnackBarComposable(
    snackBarMessage: String,
    onButtonClick: () -> Unit
) {
    var lastMessage by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
    val snackBarHostState by remember { mutableStateOf(SnackbarHostState()) }

    Scaffold(snackbarHost = {
        SnackbarHost(hostState = snackBarHostState)
    }) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(it)
        ) {
            Button(onClick = {
                onButtonClick()
            }) {
                Text(text = "Make new snack bar message")
            }

            LaunchedEffect(snackBarHostState, snackBarMessage) {
                if (lastMessage != snackBarMessage) {
                    snackBarHostState.showSnackbar(
                        snackBarMessage,
                        "label",
                        duration = SnackbarDuration.Short
                    )
                    lastMessage = snackBarMessage
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


Updated previous answer
